# How to put increment in flow chart

Tags: javascript, flowchart

I am bit confused with how to put increment in my flow chart that is in for loop.
so this are my codes:

```
            var Subject = document.getElementsByName('Item');
            alert(Subject.length);
            var hasAnySubjectChecked = false;
            var numberOfElectives = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < Subject.length; i++){
                if (Subject[i].type == "checkbox" && Subject[i].checked == true){
                    numberOfElectives++;
                    hasAnySubjectChecked = true; 
                }
            }
```

in this case its "i++", is it possible if anyone can show me how to display this event on a normal flow chart. Not the proper programming flowchart.

Comment: Check this [Drawing a Structured Flowchart](https://www.rff.com/structured_flowchart.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple for loop can be shown as below. Here `x=0` is initialization of for-loop, `x<10` is the condition in for-loop and `Increment x` means `X++` in for-loop.

[image]

[for more check this link.](https://www.rff.com/structured_flowchart.php)

[image]

Comment: is it possible if you can draw me a flowchart of the program because i am so confused. Since it doesn't have false. plus in my codes the value of subject.lenght would always be 7.

Comment: @DevPatel what do you mean by "Since it doesn't have false. "

Comment: The purpose of this loop is to count the number of item select. Whereas the for loop would always be true and hence it is never going to be false.

Comment: I believe your chart will be something like the new diagram I added

Comment: thx, so now i have an if statement based on number of checkbox selected, do i continue to add on my flow chart from false.

Comment: if it is an else you can add on the false. If you have another if condition after current IF block you can add it  just before `increment i` statement

Comment: i have edited the if statement on the question above, so where would you recommenced me to put that if statement which is outside of the loop.

Comment: It is out side the for loop. So it will be on false of for loop.  Here on the line from for loop false to "end" statement

Comment: sorry to bother you again, this time i have a while loop but with increment in the brackets, now the thing with this is if i take them from the program and put a semi colon front of it then they wouldn't function. So what would the flow chart look like.

Comment: sorry, I am not familiar with this type of while loop. I only saw one with condition in it. With your code `while(Subject = document.getElementsByName("item"); [i++])` I don't know if it is a legal syntax.

Comment: the increment [i++] is an array of increment and plus is it possible you can show me the flowchart.

Comment: The statement inside the `while(...)` come in the condition block of flow chart. You can put it as the condition. It is similar to for but without the increment and initialization statements.